# Ignore field in PHP post

Tags: php, ajax, html

I am **sending email using php**.
I am looping through all fields of form and using it in **html template**.

But, I need to ignore one field named captcha.

Original working code:

```
<body>
    <h2>Form Submission Data</h2>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
    {% for name,value in post %}
        <tr>
            <td class="colname">{{ name }}</td>
            <td>{{ value }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>

</body>
```

My modified (non working) code:

```
  <body>
    <h2>Form Submission Data</h2>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
        {% for name,value in post %}
        if({{ name }} != 'captcha')
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="colname">{{ name }}</td>
                <td>{{ value }}</td>
            </tr>
        }
    {% endfor %}
    </table>

</body>
```

**`if({{ name }} != 'captcha')`** doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you are missing some `%` in your code (are you sure it compiles?)

Try this?

```
{% for name,value in post 
      if( name  != 'captcha')
      {
      %}
        <tr>
            <td class="colname">{{ name }}</td>
            <td>{{ value }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% }
     endfor %}
```

Comment: I am getting the email now but, captcha field also comes up. How can I echo the names of variables to check it?
What I am trying to do is looping through all fieldnames, and if captcha field is present, dont show in table.

Comment: Can you confirm the name of the captcha field is ‘captcha’?

Comment: <div class="col-sm-6">
                                 <label for="email">Enter the code (case-sensitive) from the image here:</label>
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="captcha" name="captcha" >
                              </div>

Comment: Updated my answer, try the new `if` version

Comment: Still same issue. email comes with captcha

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single?

Comment: Tried double quotes. didnt work. still getting email with captcha

Comment: There must be something you’re omitting to mention. The code given does nothing fancy; should work.  How exactly are you sending the email (code above does not send email, only prints it to a table)